# Azure Data Studio "unknown property IsColumnSet"

Tags: azure-data-studio

I'm trying to use Azure Data Studio to connect to a SQL Server database.

I am able to connect to the database and view the list of objects (tables, stored procedures, etc.).

When I click to expand the "Columns" group inside a table, I get the following error from Azure Data Studio:

> unknown property IsColumnSet

I am able to expand the Keys, Constraints, Triggers, Indexes, etc. but I can't expand the Columns.

I am able to right-click and query the table to see all the columns, but I'd like to know what to do to get the columns list expanded in the server side bar tree.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Azure Data Studio. No luck.

Comment: Got the same - but only on SQL Server 2005.  Reported a bug here: https://github.com/Microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/3774

Comment: Interesting. Appreciate the bug report. I am, indeed, trying to connect to a SQL Server 2005 database. All the more reason to migrate to an updated version!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently Azure Data Services "only officially supports SQL Server 2014+" and this problem would seem to be due to lack of support for older servers.

https://github.com/Microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/3774

So although they might improve the error message to indicate lack of support, I think otherwise we're out of luck.  A long-overdue server upgrade is in order methinks...

Comment: Agree wholeheartedly! I'm just glad some other fine folks were able to inform me that the issue is related to the version of SQL Server and not something else.

We are trying to upgrade to SQL Server 2017, so hopefully once that is done I'll be back in business.

Appreciate you added the answer.

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, while this error persists in the UI when drilling down a table to view the columns, you can still get this information via SQL like so:

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'someTable';
```

Verified this works with ADS on Mac, connected to SQL Server 2005.